I am able to receive the error from an Api call in my backend but it fails to show when i read it from the frontend in Next JS
My backend with NextJS
export async function DELETE(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { productId: string } }
) {
  try {
    const storeId = '665a238f72ab3f9616e1a1d8';

    const product = await prismadb.product.deleteMany({
      where: {
        id: params.productId,
      },
    });
    return NextResponse.json(product);
  } catch (error: any) {
    return new NextResponse(
      'Please delete all transactions and auctions related with this product to continue',
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );
  }
}

This is where i make my Api call on the frontend
import { Product } from "@/types";
import qs from "query-string";


const URL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`

const deleteProduct = async (params: string): Promise<Product | any> => {
    const url = `${URL}/${params}`
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
    });

    return res.json()


}

export default deleteProduct

And this is me trying to delete the product
 const onDelete = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            if (selectedProduct == undefined) {
                toast.error('Unauthorized!')
                setLoading(false);
                return;
            }
            else {
                const deleteProductInDb = await deleteProduct(selectedProductId)
                if (!deleteProductInDb) {
                    setLoading(false)
                    return;
                }
            }
            // window.location.replace(`/dashboard/shops/${params.shopId}`)
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
        finally {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    };

When i try to delete from the backend, i am able to receive the error message but when i try it on the frontend, I get a syntax error saying

Unexpected token 'P', "Please del"... is not valid JSON

I have tried using error.response.data but it is still not working. I'm kind of new to Next JS and would love any assistance

From the looks of it, you probably want to use NextResponse.json

Or check for unsuccessful responses and use res.text() instead of res.json()

This question is similar to: Fetch: reject promise and catch the error if status is not OK?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

But if i use Nextresponse.json() , it views the operation as successful

I will try the res.text then as an error condition in my frontend and get back to you

hello@Phil , i still can't get the error to show on the frontend. it seems the error is coming from my api call on the frontend. I am expecting a json from the api call but when this fails due to some conditions, the error is still getting returned as a json object. My main issue is how to parse the text to my frontend without it coming as a json file

Found out the error. turns out the error message was stored in the variable - deleteProductInDb
